# Discrepency while console logging event and event.target in jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While writing code to change value of select tag via React. I console.log(event), while browsing through the console output(shown below) event->target = NULL
Whereas if i console.log(event.target) i get = entire list of selections available.

console.log(event) gives below output where onclicking target i get NULL

```
SyntheticEvent
bubbles: (...)
cancelable: (...)
currentTarget: (...)
defaultPrevented: (...)
dispatchConfig: null
eventPhase: (...)
isDefaultPrevented: (...)
isPropagationStopped: (...)
isTrusted: (...)
nativeEvent: (...)
target: null
....
```

Whereas this gives
Console.log(event.target)

```
<select>
<options ... ./>
...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how it works. **target** is associated with the **event**.
You will get your result through **event.target**